# Show that a certain self-adjoint operator has at least one negative eigenvalue

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Exercise 12.8 from Konrad Schmüdgen -- Unbounded Self-adjoint Operators on Hilbert Space
[image]

My question is: Is my proof correct? And, could you give another example?

### My "Proof"

Consider $f(x)=e^{-\epsilon x^2}$, we know that $\langle f,f \rangle=\int (f(x))^2=\sqrt{\pi /2\epsilon}$ and $\forall \delta>0 $  $\exists \epsilon >0$ such that
$$ \left| \int V(x)e^{-2\epsilon x^2}dx - \int V(x)dx \right| <\delta/4 $$
$$ \langle f'',f\rangle = \langle f',f'\rangle =\sqrt{\pi\epsilon/2}<\delta/4 $$So let $-\delta =\int V(x)dx$ then by above choice of $\epsilon>0$ we have
\begin{align}
\langle Tf,f \rangle &= \int V(x) e^{-2\epsilon x^2}dx + \sqrt{\frac{\pi \epsilon}{2}} \\
& \leq \int V(x)dx  + \delta/4 +\delta/4 = -\delta/2
\end{align}

Finally by the fact that (**Edit:** When T is self-adjoint and $\sigma_{ess}(T)\subseteq [0,\infty)$)  $\langle Tf,f \rangle<0$ for some $f\in D(T)$ if and only if that $T$ has negative eigenvalue.

But I don't like this because this function was given by the author for previous problem and i used it here as well. So i tried to come up with other functions...

### Search for other f(x)'s

**1)** First thing i do was, let $[a,b]\supseteq suppV$ and define,
$$f(x)= \begin{cases}
 1 \ \textrm{on} \ [a,b] \\
 1-a+x \ \textrm{on} \ [a-1,a] \\
 ...
\end{cases} $$
But, i realize that this is not differentiable for example at $x=a$.

**2)** Then i said let's make the connections smoother via some function or just by saying we can make. Then i realize that $\langle f'',f \rangle $ no longer stays zero.

**3)** Lastly but not leastly, i tried to say something like: Because $V$ is borel measurable and $\int V(x)dx<0$ then we should have an interval $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ for some $\varepsilon>0$ such that $V(x)<0$ for all $x\in(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ . But i couldn't justify.

I very much like to see my proof fail and a new function that solves. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: In general part 3. of what you've written will not be true, e.g. if you consider minus indicator of fat Cantor set.

Comment: Yes, thanks :). I was afraid of something like that as well. I thought that maybe being borel measurable not lebesgue measurable could save such justification but ...

Comment: I don't know if this will work, but what about trying to compute the [Rayleigh quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient) directly?

Comment: But rayleigh quotient requires a element from hilbert space in the first place. If you are saying for $e^{-\epsilon x^2}$ then rayleigh quotient is $\langle Tf,f\rangle$ divided by $||f||$ which is the same thing upto cosntant.

Comment: Instead of trying to search for other functions, perhaps try to understand the structure of the eigenvalue whose existence is guaranteed here.  Can we say anything about its (approximate or generalized) eigenfunctions?

Comment: Related?: http://www.math.caltech.edu/SimonPapers/70.pdf

Comment: @KeithMcClary believe this solves my problem with explicit construction for $f$. But this paper doesn't even use the compactness of support of $V$ :) . If you want to write some answer i could approve and give it an upvote. If not i'll try add the answer to my question using simon's paper when i had the time.

Comment: It might be clear from the context in Schmüdgen's book, but in general $\inf_f \langle Tf,f\rangle<0$ does not imply that $T$ has a negative eigenvalue (take $T=-\Delta-1$ on $L^2(\mathbb R)$ for example). But it is true in this setting because $V$ is relatively compact with respect to $-\Delta$.

Comment: @MaoWao Yes , you are right. Sorry for let's say lack of information. We must have that $\sigma_{ess}(T)\subseteq [0,\infty)$ as well. In order for my claim to be true. Which is the case for our $V$ by some theorems on chapter 8-10 about perturbations etc.